# Deploy utilizando o GIT em meu servidor

Tags: git, github, deploy

Olá,

Utilizo para poder fazer upload dos meus arquivos do site o GIT, fazendo deploy no meu servidor automaticamente para isso fiz o seguinte:

1 - criei um repositório GIT no meu servidor, fora da pasta public_html
2 - depois criei um arquivo post-receive dentro do diretório hooks do meu repositório, onde ele realiza o deploy para o meu servidor, com a seguinte linha

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/diretorio/public_html git checkout -f
```

Mas eu tenho alguns problemas e não sei como resolver, são eles:

**Arquivos de imagens**

- Tenho um diretório de imagens dos usuários em assets/img/users/, o problema é que toda vez que faço um PULL para o meu repositório no meu servidor este diretório é "zerado" já que os arquivos que estão no servidor não estão na minha máquina

> **Pergunta:**

- como fazer para que este diretório não seja atualizado no deploy? já tentei utilizar o .gitignore mas não funcionou

**Determinados diretórios não podem estar no deploy**

- No meu local de trabalho tenho um servidor GIT também, onde fazemos todo o PULL de nossas aplicações para outros desenvolvedores trabalharem nelas, então todos os nossos projetos possuem todos os arquivos que trabalhamos, inclusive o arquivo de diagrama do banco de dados
- Este arquivo de diagrama fica na pasta /sql/nome-do-diagrama que está dentro da minha estrutura do projeto
- Quando faço um PULL para o nosso servidor GIT interno está pasta tem que ser enviada normalmente porque é um arquivo de trabalho que outro desenvolvedor poderá utilizar, mas quando faço o PULL para o servidor de produção, que realiza o DEPLOY automaticamente esta pasta não pode ser enviada para o DEPLOY

> **Pergunta**

- Como posso fazer para que a pasta /sql ao realizar o PULL para o servidor de produção não seja incluída na ação de DEPLOY e então copiada para o servidor web?
- Já tentei utilizar o comando GIT --exclude=/home/diretorio/pasta mas não funciona

Quem puder me ajudar e me dar uma luz agradeceria

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jorge,

O que você está fazendo é a automação do seu processo de deploy, ou pipeline automation; porém o Git não é a ferramenta certa para isso. Quer dizer, é uma das ferramentas que fazem parte do processo, mas não é através dela que você irá conseguir executar todas essas suas necessidades!

1. Primeiro você faz um build, ou seja, basicamente é o processo de compilação, mas também envolve outros sub-processos. Por isso se você está usando uma linguagem não compilável, mesmo assim você terá uma etapa de build, que fará por exemplo: empacotamento, minificação de javascript, etc...
2. Depois existe o processo de deploy propiamente dito, onde você executaria, por exemplo, substituição de variáveis de ambiente, ou da string de conexão com banco de dados.

Ferramentas que tem ajudarão: make, cake, Gulp, ... Daí é só escrever scripts para automatizar o processo.
Como você não deu mais informações sobre linguagem, plataforma, etc... Não consigo te direcionar para alguma delas.

Comment: Olá Gomes, primeiramente obrigado pela resposta, hoje estou utilizando o Codeigniter para desenvolvimento, toda a minha plataforma é desenvolvida com este framework e banco de dados MySQL. Hoje não tenho este processo de deploy que cita para mimificar os arquivos, substituir variáveis, etc fazemos isso na mão ao subir os arquivos para o servidor, sendo bem sincero não sei ao certo como montar este fluxo de uma forma correta e que possa ser replicada facilmente para a equipe e para novos projetos, será que poderia me dar algumas dicas ou indicar algumas formas de se fazer isto. Obrigado

Comment: Gomes, fui pesquisar um pouco sobre GULP, achei muito interessante, já estou estudando e fiz alguns testes, mas ainda não resolve meu problema de deploy sem precisar fazer FTP. Utilizei o plugin gulp-deploy-git compilando todos os arquivos para uma pasta e realizando o deploy no servidor mas não funcionou corretamente, você teria mais ou menos uma dica de como mantar um ambiente mais favorável, acho que estamos meio perdidos